# SetFocusOnError doesn't work properly

Tags: html, asp.net, validation, webforms

the problem I have is that I have a form (asp.net form) and some of the fields (most of them) have RequiredFieldValidator. Now I also set SetFocusOnError="true" on all of them and it works fine for all but dropdowns. Let me define fine: after clicking on the Submit button while one of the fields is left blank, browser scrolls up to the empty field. In case of dropdowns the error message is indeed displayed properly next to the field however browser will not scroll up the screen to the field. I've read similar questions on stack overflow so far and they all come to "use JavaScript for this", but my problem is that I want to use asp.net property for this. If it's there it's supposed to work, right? Unless I do it wrong. Here comes the code for one of the working fields:

```
<div class ="row">
            <div class="three columns medium" align="right">
                <label>Email *</label>
            </div>
            <div class="three columns large">
                <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="six columns large">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" ControlToValidate="Email"
                    ErrorMessage="Please provide us your email address" forecolor="Red" SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="EmailFormat" ControlToValidate="Email"
                    ErrorMessage="Please provide us valid e-mail address" ValidationExpression="^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+$" forecolor="Red" runat="server" />
            </div>   
        </div>
```

and here's a sample of not working focus:

```
<div class ="three columns medium" align="right">
            <asp:DropDownList class="dropdown expand" ID="Location" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem
                    Enabled="True"
                    Text="Please choose the office location... *"
                    Value=""
                />
                <asp:ListItem
                    Enabled="True"
                    Text="City1"
                    Value="City1"
                />
                <asp:ListItem
                    Enabled="True"
                    Text="City2"
                    Value="City2"
                />
                <asp:ListItem
                    Enabled="True"
                    Text="City3"
                    Value="City3"
                />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class ="six columns large">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="LocationRequired" ControlToValidate="Location"
                ErrorMessage="Please select the office location" forecolor="Red" SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" />
        </div>
    <div class ="three columns large"></div>
```

Is my code wrong or am I expecting the wrong thing from it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the ValidationGroup property of the each of the controls involved in this, such as the Drop Down List, Button, Required Field Validator etc as

`ValidationGroup="Selection`"

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid it's not changing anything. Still validation works and error messages are displayed but I have to scroll to the dropdowns to see them...

Comment: well, it should work....i just tested, and in chrome, the browser automatically sets the focus to drop down and i dont need to scroll

Comment: Do you use standard html <Select> tag? Because I use the foundation css and I suppose this is where it breaks...

Answer (score 0):

I afraid that 3rd party scripts like jqTransform break something in asp.net script that is setting focus on error controls. Try to remove 3rd party scripts and check. If they were cause then you need to invent something with java script